# How to make arr.includes(someVar) works with typed arrays when checking against a variable that can exist in all arrays?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to make this type guard work. The issue is that the variable currentType could be a type that is included in two arrays. However, when I pass the currentType as a parameter to the includes method, it errors out and says it cannot be assigned. Why? I am type checking against the variable, I am not assigne it i just want to check if it could be there, to begin with. I cannot ditch those types since they ensure stability in the code. How can I make such a check possible without using a predicate or (casting if casting in this case could result in runtime error)?

```
Argument of type '"b3"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"a1" | "a2" | "a3"'.(2345)
```

```js
type TypeA = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'];
const typeAArr: TypeA = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'];
type TypeB = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'];
const typeBArr: TypeB = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'];

type AllTypes = 'a1' | 'a2' | 'a3' | 'b1' | 'b2' | 'b3';
let currentType: AllTypes = 'b3'; // will be changed based on the case

// Guard for typeAArr
if (typeAArr.includes(currentType)) {
  console.log('currentType is in typeAArr');
}

// Guard for typeBArr
if (typeBArr.includes(currentType)) {
  console.log('currentType is in typeBArr');
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEEEoF4oG0DkBDAjBgNFNgEwFFYDMGAugNwBQAxgPYB2AzsFKJAggE78AXLHhJUmXGRLTKNBj2hxIAIRToMAIzyEtpXZqp0mbTt3gqBw0avWZt0zfqKH59eoqgIANt%20UR2dWw8KAAfclIw8ioorRDwvQxY1wZvCC5GAFdBCFZgfxEfP3hA1C0qWigAeiqoAHcAS18oTWhGAAssVgBzCAATFqx2fqg2bna2oYh3GqgAcUysfgGAM2Z%20c14regaVqAAKRT5BADoG1kZvTL6A-aycvP8ASieoAG96KCgWDmY0k%208zG6%20ww934uXy8CgDUC502iCsGCeDAAvjNagslqt1vDLIIdntDhYrGcLlcbuw7tlwY94C93p9vqY-hAAUCQWCIf5obDWLjEcj6CigA)

Comment: Can you create a typescript playground. Do not understand some of the syntax https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBKkIJQLxQOQEMCMKoB9VoCZs90BmFAbgCgBjAewDsBnYGcCOOAJy4C434SKAG10WADToi4-OQC6VWNCUAhISgBGWXKg1Edm8tVqMWAiCu59za5KK0pJex7vlVF7KHAA23gCrsTOqYKDhSoWShulhhziQa5FTeEKw0AK48EAzAAZD8Pv6B6gnYAPSlUADuAJa+UBrQNAAWaAwA5hBBGmhMEAAmUIxQND0Q7lTlUADiaWhcfVTVAGYAFEqcPAB01Qw03ml9nSvpmdm5EACUFwDe7gC+7uXLa+yWWzt7B0dXt+V3QA

Comment: Reading past the syntax errors, though, I suspect you're running into the issue that TypeScript won't let you check a value that doesn't have `typeA` in `typeAArr.includes`. There are several existing questions w/answers about that. The general solution is to widen the type of `typeAArr` with an assertion: `if ((typeAArr as AllTypes[]).includes(currentType))`. That usually comes up when accepting raw values from an API, rather than typed values like `currentType`, though; with a more closely typed value like that, it's usually possible to avoid this with logic. FWIW: https://tsplay.dev/WKKdzW

Comment: Sorry for the syntax thing, I passed to ts playground, now it is working , you can clearly see the error when checking the type against the first array type, since the value could be a shared type, I am setting a conditional rendering logic based on this.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder your solution work as a workaround the issue but i need a solution that makes code readable my bet is on charging the method to typeAArr.some(el=> el === currentType) this will allow better readably... (for me) since it is subjective.